# What is this kind of tag {{code here}} inside a HTML document?

Tags: html, tags

I found this tags:

```
{{define "content"}}

{{end}}

{{range .Photos}}
```

Inside a HTML document.

So, what do they mean ?

Comment: machine tags used by templating engines. They are indicators that the system has to do some kind of processing based on the values in the {{}} brackets.

Comment: Perhaps mustache http://mustache.github.io or some other templating code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://scalate.fusesource.org/documentation/mustache.html)

> Mustache provides logic-less templates which also work inside the
>   browser using mustache.js - **so ideal for HTML templates which your
>   designers own.**

Example:

```
Hello {{name}} 
You have just won ${{value}}!
{{#in_ca}}
Well, ${{taxed_value}}, after taxes.
{{/in_ca}}
```

Given the following attributes:

```
Map(
  "name" -> "Chris",
  "value" -> 10000,
  "taxed_value" -> 10000 - (10000 * 0.4),
  "in_ca" -> true
  )
```

Will produce the following:

```
Hello Chris
You have just won $10000!
Well, $6000.0, after taxes.
```

Comment: Is there any site with a documentation about these tags ? Like what {{end}} means, {{content}}

Comment: @Murilo:- The site added by Pierre is a good one to proceed with.